# Drupal db connectivity

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, mamp

I am setting up Drupal 7.9 on my MAC OS X lion. I have it installed under MAMP/HTDOCS, copied default.settings.php to settings.php, changed the write permission for settings.php. I am trying to setup my database but keep running into the following error:

Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost/phpMyAdmin' (61).
```

I am able to access localhost/phpmyadmin very easily, the username, password and database have been specified. The database has been created at phpMyAdmin as well and the correct name is specified. This is leaving me pretty clueless as to what mistake I am making out here.

I haven't made any changes in the settings.php file, I am not sure what to do.

Any of you have a solution to this or have experienced a similar problem, that would be great!

Thanks much, Happy coding!!!

Comment: The name of your database is `phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: altered db server address to localhost, name of db is not phpMyAdmin, the results are exactly the same as before

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're setting your database server address as `localhost/phpMyAdmin`...it should just be `localhost`

Comment: I altered it to localhost, but no positive results, the exact same statement plays itself back.

Answer (score 1):

Check you settings.php (located at sites/default). Look at line 180 the database settings should look like

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'database_name',
      'username' => 'user_name',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```